# Confusion showing continuity of a function in a problem?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to answer the following problem:

> [image]

I know that I can convert $X,Y$ to metric spaces by considering the metric $d_X(\mathtt{X},\mathtt{Y})=\max (d_i(x_i,y_i))$  with:

$$\mathtt{X}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\hspace{2cm} \mathtt{Y}=(y_1,\dots,y_n) \hspace{2cm}x_i,y_i\in X_i $$

And $d_Y(\mathtt{X'},\mathtt{Y'})=\max (d'_i(x'_i,y'_i))$ with:

$$\mathtt{X'}=(x'_1,\dots,x'_n)\hspace{2cm} \mathtt{Y'}=(y'_1,\dots,y'_n) \hspace{2cm} x'_i,y'_i\in Y_i $$

Now, I guess I must prove that for any $A\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that:

$$\max{d_i(x_i,a_i)} < \delta \quad \implies \quad \max{d'_i(f_i(x_i),f_i(a_i))}<\epsilon$$

But I am really confused at what should be done next. I guess that the continuity on $f_i$ might show that two points $x_i,a_i$ "near" one another in $X_i$ must also be "near" when we think about $f_i(x_i),f_i(a_i)$ in $Y$. But it's not clear how I should write it (assuming this is correct).

Comment: All you have to do is take minimum of $n \,\,\,  \delta$'s.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Good. But how should I argue? And what relation $\min \delta_n$ has with $\epsilon?$

Comment: Note that if $d_i(x_i y_i) < \delta$ for all $i$ then d_X(x,y) < \delta$ too…